# Python: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] in my chat program when connecting twice

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat

Currently I'm working on a live chat program. I've followed a tutorial online, and the outcome was a working live chat.

It consists of a server file and a client file.

The error happens when i close the client file and join the same server instance.
From the client side i can't send a message. In the server commandprompt it gives this error:

```
Waiting for connection...
192.168.0.81:61453 connected to server.
192.168.0.81:61456 connected to server.
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\Desktop\Programmering\troubleshoot\server.py", line 19, in handle_client
    broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\Desktop\Programmering\troubleshoot\server.py", line 36, in broadcast
    sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

As far as I can read on the internet, it is because there is an active connection from the same adress. Does this mean the program doesn't close the client properly?

This problem also occurs, when other clients from other networks connect.

I'm not quite a newbie but neither an expert at Python, so in dept explanation is much appreciated.

Server.py:

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def accept_incoming_connections():                                                          
    while True:                                                                             
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()                                            
        print("%s:%s connected to server." % client_address)                            
        client.send(bytes("Type your name and press enter.", "utf8"))  
        addresses[client] = client_address                                                  
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()                                


def handle_client(client):                                                                  
    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")                                               
    welcome = 'Welcome %s! Type {stop} to exit.' % name                          
    client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))                                                     
    msg = "%s connected to the chat!" % name                                           
    broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))                                                          
    clients[client] = name                                                                  

    while True:                                                                             
        msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)                                                           
        if msg != bytes("{stop}", "utf8"):                                                  
            broadcast(msg, name+": ")                                                       
        else:
            client.send(bytes("{stop}", "utf8"))                                            
            client.close()                                                                  
            del clients[client]                                                             
            broadcast(bytes("%s leaved the chat." % name, "utf8"))                      
            break


def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):                                                              
    for sock in clients:                                                                  
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)                                                


clients = {}                                                                               
addresses = {}                                                                             

HOST = '192.168.0.81'                                                                       
PORT = 33000                                                                               
BUFSIZ = 1024                                                                               
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)                                                                       

SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)                                                      
SERVER.bind(ADDR)                                                                          

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)                                                                        
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)                              
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()                                                                  
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()                                                                    
    SERVER.close()
```

Client.py:

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import tkinter

def receive():                                                                                          
    while True:                                                                                         
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")                                             
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)                                                        
        except OSError:                                                                                 
            break

def send(event=None):                                                                               
    msg = my_msg.get()                                                                                
    my_msg.set("")                                                                                 
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))                                                          
    if msg == "{stop}": 
        client_socket.close()                                                                        
        top.quit()                                                                                 

def on_closing(event=None):                                                                            
    my_msg.set("{stop}")                                                                            
    send()                                                                                       

top = tkinter.Tk()                                                                                    
top.title("Corona chat")                                                                                
messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)                                                                   

scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)                                                          
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=50, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)          
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)                                                   
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)                                                    
msg_list.pack()                                                                                      
messages_frame.pack()                                                                                   

my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()                                                                        
my_msg.set("")  
entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)                                                  
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)                                                                
entry_field.pack()                                                                                   
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)                                        
send_button.pack()                                                                                   

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)                                                            

HOST = input('Enter host: ')                                                            
PORT = input('Enter port: ')                                                                  
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000                                                                                       
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024                                                                                        
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)                                                                                    

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)                                                        
client_socket.connect(ADDR)                                                                         

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)                                                               
receive_thread.start()                                                                           
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, this about your working procedure, on same machine need type max_connection, dynamic_source_port etc. Remember just one app can use only one port, you can't share if don't use an `.listen(x)` declaration.

Comment: On python: **if you want create an client socket use `create_connection()`**

Comment: @dsgdfg
I'm not quite sure how to implement your solution in the program. Is there a chance that you might explain it more in dept?

Comment: I just figured it out myself.

If anyone else is interested in the solution, it is pretty simple. In the server file line 27 i just realized that the `client.send(bytes("{stop}", "utf8"))` wasn't necessary.

Comment: This was caused by what you sent from the server not being read by the client before it closed the connection.

Comment: @RasmusA.C. I'm facing a similar problem . Could you please take a look at my question and help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823716/exception-in-socket-threading-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-m